# Поиск элемента в коллекции

Tags: java, коллекции, интерфейс

В рамках изучения `Generics`, никак не могу решить одну задачку.

Условие:
Метод `findFirst()` в классе  `CollectionsHelper`. Метод должен найти первый элемент в коллекции `humans`, который имеет имя, которое начинается с namePrefix и соответствующего пола `sex`, и вернуть результат. Если элемент не найден - вернуть `null`.
`Human` является интерфейсом, у которого есть два геттера(getName() и getSex()), методы этого интерфейса реализованы в классах `Men`, `Woman` и `Intersex`, в которых данные методы переопределены. `Sex` является ENUM.

Написал собственную реализацию, используя `startsWith` и для сравнения и `equals()`, но столкнулся с тем, что не могу пройти проверку. Как мне кажется основная моя ошибка, в инициализации коллекции, т.к. в моем случае происходит инициализация первого элемента в переменной `elements`, который возвращается по итогу работы метода, но как реализовать иначе, не знаю. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

```java
   public class CollectionsHelper <T extends Human> {

      public T findFirst(final List<T> humans, final String namePrefix, 
                         final Sex sex) {

         T element = humans.get(0);
            for (T human: humans){
               if (sex.equals(human.getSex()) && namePrefix.startsWith(namePrefix)){
                    element = human;
                    return element;
                }
                else {
                    element = null;
                    return element;
                }

            }
            return element;
        }
    }
```

В качестве примера прикладываю класс `Man`, реализующий интерфейс `Human`. Другие классы аналогичные, меняются только внутренние данные.

```java
public class Man implements Human {

   private final String name;

   public Man(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }


    @Override
    public Sex getSex() {
        return Sex.M;
    }


    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всмотримся в этот код:

```
namePrefix.startsWith(namePrefix)
```

Что-то здесь не то.

---

```
    for (T human: humans) {
        if (sex.equals(human.getSex()) && human.getName().startsWith(namePrefix))
            return human;
    }
    return null;
```

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, что это очень хороший вопрос(за вопрос плюсик от меня), на котором можно многому научиться, посему постараюсь дать подробный ответ. Я не буду останавливаться на ошибках в коде, которые были указаны в предыдущем ответе(думаю, что с этим уже разобрались).

В этом случае функциональный подход лучше. Назначение стримов - работа с множествами(коллекциями, массивами и т д), это именно то, что нам нужно, а значит код будет более лаконичным и, как следствие, более читаемым. Мало того, если бы я писал утилитарный класс (что само по себе не очень здорово, потому как класс-утилита в большей части случаев в ооп говорит о том, что вы не совсем корректно построили архитектуру в пределах своей предметной области и теперь вам просто не к чему пристроить какой-либо функционал), то я бы постарался сделать его максимально универсальным, чтобы в дальнейшем максимально переиспользовать его. Посему я написал метод findFirst, типизированный собственным дженериком, принимающий Predicate, а также Iterable вместо List. Теперь этот метод, с одной стороны, может работать с коллекциями любых объектов, с другой стороны не ограничен только наследниками List. Данный метод функционально реализовывается довольно просто. Но текущая ваша задача такова, что нам нужно работать только с классами, имплементирующими Human, при этом условия фильтрации уже предопределены. Поэтому второй метод принимает только наследников указанного интерфейса, вызывая наш универсальный метод. Поскольку нам уже известы условия фильтрации, а список мы принимаем в аргументах, то остается лишь написать предикат. Таим образом, вы получите максимально гибкую конструкцию.

```
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class CollectionsHelper<T extends Human> {

    public T findFirst(final Iterable<T> humans, final String namePrefix, final Sex sex) {
        return findFirst(humans, human -> sex == human.getSex() && human.getName().startsWith(namePrefix));
    }
    
    public <K> K findFirst(final Iterable<K> iterable, final Predicate <K> predicate) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false).filter(predicate).findFirst().orElse(null);
    }
    
}
```

Есть еще одна проблема, которая не имеет прямого отношения к вопросу, но все же... Это ваш класс Man. В таком виде он абсолютно бессмысленный. Корректнее сделать так:

```
public class HumanImpl implements Human{
    
    private final Sex sex;    
    private final String name;

    public HumanImpl(Sex sex, String name) {
        this.sex = sex;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Sex getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
}
```

Как минимум, вам теперь не нужно писать имплементации под каждый енам. Мало того, в случае расширения (добавления новых полей), они будут добавлены в один класс, а не во все имплементации. Расширении енама также не вызывает никаких проблем.
Единственный видимый (на первый взгляд) минус - процесс создзания экземпляров данного класса, ведь new Man("name") выглядит предпочтительнее new HumanImpl (Sex.m, "name"). Это так, но на самом деле оба варианта провальные, потому как приводят к высокой связанности кода (все классы, создающие экземпляры классов, имплементирующих Human, теперь имеют ссылку на классы, а не на сам интерфейс). Посему корректнее использовать паттрен фабричный метод. Теперь интерфейс будет выглядеть так:

```
interface Human {
    
    public Sex getSex();
        
    public String getName();
    
    public static Human createHuman(String name, Sex sex){
        return new HumanImpl(sex, name);
    }    
    public static Human createMan(String name){
        return createHuman(name, Sex.M);
    }
    public static Human createWoman(String name){
        return createHuman(name, Sex.W);
    }
    
}
```

Как видите, теперь у нас есть 3 метода : один универсальнй, принимающий 2 параметра, и два специфические для Man и Woman. Вполне очевидно, что даже при расширении енама Sex количество именно Man и Woman будет подавляющим, остальные же экземпляры можно создать через универсальный статический метод, не прибегая к написанию доп.методов в интерфейсе.

И только в случае реальной необходимости создания классов Man и Woman и т.д стоит наследовать их от класса HumanImpl(который , вероятно, станет в этом случае абстрактным). Тогда наши классы Man и Woman приобретут очень тривиальный вид:

```
public class Man extends HumanImpl {
    
    public Man(String name) {
        super(Sex.M, name);
    }
    
}

public class Woman extends HumanImpl {
    
    public Woman(String name) {
        super(Sex.W, name);
    }
    
}
```

Если есть вопросы - пишите.Удачи